# Calculate the physical object size in m knowing its distance ,focal length and pixel size in image

Tags: python, camera, camera-calibration

I am programming a code in python that compare the detected object size in the image in pixels with its actual physical dimensions from different distances in a way that I know the focal length, distance and digital sensor of the camera.

I am looking for a solution which gives me the physical dimension if I give the object size in pixel in the captured image, then know the distance to the camera and focal length. Then I would like to compare that calculate physical dimension with the actual real object dimension. For example, I know that the real width of the object is 20cm, real height is 40 cm, the distance is 1.1 m, and the focal length is 8mm. My object detection OpenCV code gives me object height is 285 pixels, width is 132 pixels.

I assume the object is parallel to the camera so it is considered as a 2D object.

here is the python code

```
    actual_H =0.4 #meter
    actual_W =0.2#meter

    F =0.008 #meter_focal_lenght
    Dist = 1.1 #meter distance  
    height=285 #pixel
    width=132  #pixel

    #do calculation
    pix_H =(Dist*float(height))/F
    pix_W =(Dist*float(width))/F
    print feature +"******************"
    print "Pixel Dimension :"+str(float(height))+":"+str(float(width))
    print "Physical Dimension:"+str(pix_H)+":"+str(pix_W)


   #comparision actual and pix
    if (  (pix_H <= actual_H) and (pix_W <= actual_W)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This calculation is wrong. But dont know where is the problem. Im using this Formula

```
object size in image = focal length * object size / object distance
```

Any help?

Comment: How have you calculated the focal Length, because as far as I remember focal Length should be in Pixels and this is further supported by the fact that above equation will have same dimension only when focal Length is in Pixels.

Comment: and for your case I guess  1mm = 100 pixels, because with these I got quite close results :-D

Comment: I just take the value from the camera. In the camera specs said Focal length is Auto Focus 2.8-12mm. So how to calculate that in pixels?

Comment: camera Calibration is the process to calculate focal Length in pixels. Have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

Comment: ok. So I should download that program code? And after that? how can incorporate that in my python code?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.scantips.com/lights/subjectdistance.html), you probably also need to know the sensor dimension and the dim of resolution in order to resolve this. To understand better, check the following picture [image: following picture]

Here is a code snippet I had prepared some time ago for calculating something similar

```py
#Requires 1)Real object size, 2)Distance from object and returns ---> Object_size in pixels
def given_real_get_pixels(Object_length_meters,Object_width_meters,distance):
    
    Object_width_on_sensor_mms=(Focal_length*Object_width_meters)/distance
    #Object_width_on_sensor_mms2
    Object_width_pixels=(Sensor_width_pixels*Object_width_on_sensor_mms)/Sensor_width_mms

    Object_length_on_sensor_mms=(Focal_length*Object_length_meters)/distance
    Object_length_pixels=(Sensor_length_pixels*Object_length_on_sensor_mms)/Sensor_length_mms
    
    print(f'Object_actual_size={Object_length_meters} x {Object_width_meters}(meters) at {distance}(meters) distance coresponds to Object_pixel_size={Object_length_pixels} x {Object_width_pixels}(pixels)')
    return Object_width_pixels,Object_length_pixels  

#Requires 1)distance from object, 2)Object width in pixels and returns ---> Object_size in meters
def given_pixels_get_real(distance,Object_width_pixels,Object_length_pixels):
    Object_width_on_sensor_mms=(Sensor_width_mms*Object_width_pixels)/Sensor_width_pixels    
    Object_width_meters=((distance*Object_width_on_sensor_mms)/Focal_length)

    Object_length_on_sensor_mms=(Sensor_length_mms*Object_length_pixels)/Sensor_length_pixels
    Object_length_meters=((distance*Object_length_on_sensor_mms)/Focal_length)

    print(f'Object_pixel_size={Object_length_pixels} x {Object_width_pixels}(pixels) at {distance}(meters) distance corresponds to Object_actual_size={Object_length_meters} x {Object_width_meters}(meters)')
    return Object_width_meters,Object_length_meters

def given_real_and_pixels_get_distance(Object_length_meters,Object_width_meters,Object_length_pixels,Object_width_pixels):

    Object_width_on_sensor_mms=(Sensor_width_mms*Object_width_pixels)/Sensor_width_pixels
    distance_width=(Focal_length*Object_width_meters)/Object_width_on_sensor_mms

    Object_length_on_sensor_mms=(Sensor_length_mms*Object_length_pixels)/Sensor_length_pixels
    distance_length=(Focal_length*Object_length_meters)/Object_length_on_sensor_mms
        
    print(f'For obtaining an Object_pixel_size={Object_length_pixels} x {Object_width_pixels}(pixels) of an object that has Object_actual_size={Object_length_meters} x {Object_width_meters}(meters), distance must be distance_length = {distance_length}(meters) and distance_width= {distance_width}(meters) and mean_distance(suggested)={(distance_length+distance_width)/2}(meters) ')
    return distance_length,distance_width

#################################################### Define Specifications ######################################################
#Sensor 
Sensor_length_mms=7.410 #mm
Sensor_width_mms=4.980 #mm
Sensor_length_pixels=3088 #pixels
Sensor_width_pixels=2076 #pixels
#Focal length
Focal_length=9.6 #mm

######################################################### Define Parameters ######################################################
distance=125 #0.8 # meters

################################################# GET OBJECT SIZE IN PIXELS ######################################################

Object_length_meters=0.60
Object_width_meters=0.40 #meters
Object_width_pixels,Object_length_pixels=given_real_get_pixels(Object_length_meters,Object_width_meters,distance)

################################################# GET OBJECT SIZE IN METERS ######################################################
Object_length_pixels=Object_width_pixels=20
Object_width_meters,Object_length_meters=given_pixels_get_real(distance,Object_width_pixels,Object_length_pixels)

########################################### GET DISTANCE TO OBJECT IN METERS ######################################################
Object_length_meters=1
Object_width_meters=1 #meters
Object_length_pixels=100
Object_width_pixels=100

distance_length,distance_width=given_real_and_pixels_get_distance(Object_length_meters,Object_width_meters,Object_length_pixels,Object_width_pixels)
```