# calculate focal length with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera

i've ran the calibrate.py program and it gave me the following results:

RMS: 0.704899159499
camera matrix:

[[  9.96458125e+02   0.00000000e+00   6.44868566e+02]

[  0.00000000e+00   1.03116379e+03   3.66596086e+02]

[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]

distortion coefficients:  [ 0.11207317  0.04385525  0.00172074 -0.00937101 -1.33862181]

how can i use this data to calculate the focal length of my webcam?

Comment: Well the camMat(0,0) and camMat(1, 1) gives fx and fy respectively.

Comment: @Optimus1072 how can i determine the length in mm using that data?

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844117/calculate-the-physical-object-size-in-m-knowing-its-distance-focal-length-and-p